# KO Grid unable to save data from edited cell - with Plunker

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, plunker, kogrid

I have an Asp.Net MVC website for which I've started to use the knockoutjs kogrid to display grids of data.

For one particular grid, I would like the user to be able to edit an Email Address column. On clicking a save button the edited value should persist to a database.

I am able to present the grid ok, and on selecting a row the user can type into the required cell. My problem is, I haven't figured out how to reference the *changed* cell value.

Here is the definition for my grid options:

```
var emailCellTemplate = '<div><input type=\"text\" data-bind=\"visible: $parent.selected(), value: $parent.entity[$data.field]" /><span data-bind=\"visible: !$parent.selected(), text: $parent.entity[$data.field]\"></span></div>'
this.gridOptions = {
    height: 200,
    afterSelectionChange: function () { return true; },
    data: self.workflowRules,
    enablePaging: true,
    pagingOptions: self.pagingOptions,
    filterOptions: self.filterOptions,
    selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
    selectedItems: self.selected,
    canSelectRows: true,
    displaySelectionCheckbox: true,
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'ReceivePortName', displayName: 'Receive Port', width: 130 },
                { field: 'MessageType', displayName: 'Message Type', width: 400 },
                { field: 'TriggerSource', displayName: 'Source', width: 150 },
                { field: 'TargetEmailAddress', displayName: 'Email', width: 180, cellTemplate: emailCellTemplate },
                { field: 'AssignedToName', displayName: 'Assigned To', width: 140 },
    ]
};
```

*$parent.entity[$data.field]* is great for selecting the value that was loaded from the database but doesn't give me the edited value. When I place a breakpoint on the js code that runs when my *Save to Database* button is clicked, then I do get to see the edited value in *WorkflowRules.TargetEmailAddress* but I have't figured out how to bind to it.

I have created a plunk to help illustrate here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ibc0WZwyb4melgNDzcUo

Could anyone please advise how I need to set my emailCellTemplate?

Comment: How do you want to use the changed data? You can find it in `vm.workflowRules()`

Comment: In your example link there is an error `vm is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I have now tracked down the cause of the bug.

The problem was in my *savetoDatabase* function of my javascript controller. The controller did define an observeable `this.workflowRules = ko.observableArray(vm.WorkflowRules);` but within the *saveToDatabase* function it used the server view model when converting to JSON prior to calling the server controller `var jsSaveModel = ko.toJS(vm);`

In order to fix this, I added an extra line to update the *WorkflowRules* array of the vm with the content of the observable before converting to JSON, so I now have

```
vm.WorkflowRules = this.workflowRules();
var jsSaveModel = ko.toJS(vm);
```